# Why catch at the end of promise chain is not catching all the errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

i have simple validation promises in my code which i execute like so

```
inBlacklist(address)
    .then(isUsed(payments))
    .then(isProcessed(ref_num))
    .then(validateType(type))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
    });
```

Which basically checks if the payment is propertly processed or not.

Here are the promises

```
export const isUsed = (payments) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (payments) {
            const paymentsData = payments.map((i) => {
                i.date = moment(i.date).startOf('minute').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
                i.amount = parseInt(i.amount);
                return i;
            });

            Transaction.findOne(paymentsData)
                .exec()
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.length) {
                        reject({ message: 'Payment is already used', status: 409 });
                    } else {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        }
    });

export const inBlacklist = (address) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Blacklist.exists({ blocked: true, address })
            .then((blocked) => {
                
                if (blocked) {
                    return reject({ message: 'Address is in blacklist', status: 406 });
                } else {
                    return resolve(false);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return reject(err);
            });
    });

export const isProcessed = (ref_num) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (ref_num) {
            Transaction.exists({ ref_num, status: { $in: ['processing', 'expired', 'resolved'] } })
                .exec()
                .then((data) => {
                    return reject({ message: 'Payment is already used', status: 422 });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        } else {
            return resolve(false);
        }
    });

export const validateType = (type) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const validTypes = ['bitcoin', 'dash'];

        if (validTypes.includes(type)) {
            return resolve();
        } else {
            return reject({ message: 'Invalid crypto type', status: 422 });
        }
    });
```

Now when i call the chain, it only works in case when `inBlacklist` was rejected. For the others it appears as an unhandled error, which just shows up on console and doesnt return the response for api.

I have also tried this

```
Promise.all([inBlacklist(address), isUsed(payments), isProcessed(ref_num), validateType(type)]).catch((err) => {
    return res.status(err.status || 400).send({ message: err.message });
});
```

Which works fine, but what if i want to use the first variant? Why i cant catch all the promise rejections in one .catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that `isUsed` is being executed *immediately* rather than after `inBlacklist` resolves, so your `.then()` is being given a Promise object rather than a callback function. It's just like if you wrote `a(b(c));`, `b` is executed first and then the return value is passed to `a`.

Instead, you want to pass to `.then` a callback function that executes the next function, so try using arrow functions inside the `then`s, like so:

```js
inBlacklist(address)
    .then(() => isUsed(payments))
    .then(() => isProcessed(ref_num))
    .then(() => validateType(type))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
    });
```

Comment: It actually worked, wth

Comment: @Areg it's to do with the order things are executed in. This way delays them until the callback happens, whereas before they were all executing outside of the `then`s

Comment: Very useful info, thank you!